# What is this RichText Error from my PowerPoint.run (powerpoint addin)?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I'm currently developing an Add-In for powerpoint. The basic features are:

- Select the current slide
- Select all the shapes and its textFrame
- Send all the found text to my backend to check for grammar/spelling
  errors
- Send response back and underline the textRange by the offset and
  length from my backend.

Everything seems to go well with a simple slide of just text boxes or shapes with texts.

The issue seems to come when a slide has text boxes inside a box that controls the text boxes size (see below image).

[image]

The error isn't so clear:

> RichApi.Error: InvalidArgument

This part gets highlighted when I check the log/source

[image]

I took the two text boxes outside of that wrapper (the extra square around the two text boxes), and it went just fine.
Why?